# How to change the ProgressBarTrackHeight height in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, xaml, progress-bar, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I want to change the height of the ProgressBarTrackHeight of the progressbar in WinUI-3. I dont know how to do it please help me with a code example.

```xml
<ProgressBar Width="130" Value="30" />
```

[image: Progressbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/pull/6061#issuecomment-976479895) about this in the GitHub repo.

As a workaround, until the issue gets fixed, you can create a custom `ProgressBar`:

```cs
public class CustomProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    private long _heightPropertyChangedCallBackToken;

    public CustomProgressBar() : base()
    {
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
        Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _heightPropertyChangedCallBackToken = RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(HeightProperty, OnHeightPropertyChanged);
        ApplyHeight();
    }

    private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UnregisterPropertyChangedCallback(HeightProperty, _heightPropertyChangedCallBackToken);
    }

    private void ApplyHeight()
    {
        foreach (FrameworkElement element in this.FindDescendants()
            .OfType<FrameworkElement>()
            .Where(x => x is Grid or Rectangle))
        {
            element.Height = Height;
        }
    }

    private void OnHeightPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        ApplyHeight();
    }
}
```

Now the `Height` property should just work:

```xml
<local:CustomProgressBar
    Height="50"
    Width="130"
    Value="30" />
```

Note that `FindDescendants` is from the [CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) NuGet package.

**UPDATE**

In the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/9010#issuecomment-1776698078), a better option was suggested for the case that you won't change the `Height` dynamically. Instead of creating a custom `ProgressBar`, you just need to set the `MinHeight`:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Double x:Key="ProgressBarTrackHeight">50</x:Double>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <ProgressBar
        MinHeight="{StaticResource ProgressBarTrackHeight}"
        Maximum="100"
        Value="70" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Posted a new [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/9010) on the repo.

Comment: thank you so much sir for helping this works well setting the min height worked well.